# PHP inside HTML doesn't work

Tags: php, html, echo

I just want to know why does this HTML file shows nothing:

- I'm running it on a web server
- Name of the file is index.php
- I've fixed the `<?` issue but it still doesn't work

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
            <?php
            echo "hdfguhbgzusgdfghdhhfgh";       
            ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It can be because apache2 don't know this is a php file.
Usually, you only have to set the extension of your file as ".php"

You should use <?php instead of <?

Comment: Are you running a web server? If you're just opening an HTML file in the browser, this won't work.

Comment: since it has php part, the file should be saved with .php extension, and the server should support php, also, please use `<?php` instead of `<?` just for ensuring that everything is correct.

Comment: You gave us not enough info to help you. Do you have webserver running? Do you have short_open_tag enabled in php.ini? What about extension and settings for it?

Comment: @nickflees if he wasn't running a server he would see php code. I would guess short tags are disabled.

Comment: what is your file extension?

Comment: @DS9 Can't be an extension issue. If he served this as a .html page it wouldn't be blank. You would see the PHP in the browser if it wasn't parsed.

Comment: Check your Apache logs to see if there's any errors in there.

Comment: I had the same problem: my mistake was the HTML extension. Changing to PHP solved the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should make sure that following are given:

- PHP on your server
- Files have to end with ".php"
- Use open Tag `<?php` and not `<?`

Then it should work.

For a definite solution you should provide further information.

Comment: It works on another server so there must be something wrong with mine one. Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 4):

As edited by [halfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer) on Apr 8 '14 at 14:13, the showing code had no `<?` problem anymore. The code seemed well written.

In case those code still do not work, perhaps people must add:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

inside the `.htaccess` file.

The `.htaccess` file must be in the same directory with your `html` file. If you can't found the `.htaccess` file although you already turning on the show hidden file option, you can create new `.htaccess` file and include AddHandler mentioned above in the file.

Just create a blank text file and name it with `.htaccess` on the mentioned directory.

Answer (score 0):

you missed `php` after `<?`

so, change:

```
<? echo "hdfguhbgzusgdfghdhhfgh";  ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo "hdfguhbgzusgdfghdhhfgh";  ?>
```

Comment: If short_open_tag is enabled in php.ini this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- If you dont see the text, try to open source code in browser.
- Make sure, that your file is .php and not .html
- Use `<?php` as opening tag instead `<?`
- If you want to just echo text, you can use `<?echo "YourText"; ?>`

Everything else seems OK

Answer (score 0):

The short_tags comes disabled by default, so you have to use

```
<?php
  echo 'Teste';   
?>
```

invés de:

```
<?
  echo 'Teste';   
?>
```

To enable the option to just turn short_tag in php.ini
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

PS: For performance reasons it is recommend to use "(double quotes) only when the echo is variable, so that PHP will parse and find the variable If you place." (Double quotes) there is no variable in the php echo to atoa parsing, try waste of charge.

Answer (score -1):

Phew, 9 years ago! But, I just wanted to add that you can do a short hand syntax like this: `<?= 'Some text' ?>`

while the long hand would be: `<?php echo 'Some text' ?>`

PHP is great and will be around for a long time!