Post to PHP errs wtih "The requested URL was not found on this server." via action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' Fixes?
I'm trying to skip having TWO files for PHP form validation and processing using a target of $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] in the action specification.
Of course, for security, it's a little more sophisticated, using:
<form method="post" action='<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>'>

Example code and more is readily found at the w3Schools.com site, such as this example, but one of many. And yes, I've got that very one on my site now, and it has visible issues, though this command shows no errors:
$ php -l index.html 
No syntax errors detected in index.html

(I DID find an error, already fixed here: double quotes were used around the action AND within the action, so the outer ones were exchanged for single quotes. But the php -l DIDN'T find that one!)
No matter what I try, it just doesn't work on my systems?! In reading the literature it seems perfectly reasonable, why you'd want to do this, how to secure it, all known and I'd guess I've used countless sites that do this very thing on places I've interacted with in the past since they don't move me to another page upon posting.
My guess is it has something to do with the voluminous permissions PHP has at hand. I dug through them and found nothing obvious; anyone?
I can of course give lots of platform data but then, if this is caused by a specific permission, that may be immaterial.

The webserver won't execute php code inside a .html file, unless you reconfigure its settings. You'd need to rename the file as .php if you want php code within it to be executed. I'd imagine your form is literally trying to post back to a URL something like http://<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> which naturally doesn't exist on your server. Thar should be visible in the browser bar when you try to submit the form (unless it gets submitted via ajax of of course, but you didn't mention that). It should also be visible if you use the View Source tool in your browser.

@ADyson THANKS! The_Answer was simply to rename the file from .html to .php! WOW! HOURS banging my head on a wall for nothing! ... Please make that an answer and I'll happily accept it! :-)

No problem. It should just be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939278/php-inside-html-doesnt-work or several other similar questions, tbh. Not sure we need a new answer to the same thing :-). Or feel free to delete it before that inevitable closure occurs, and save the community a job.

@ADyson Frustrating; based on the title, why wouldn't I have found that? IDK but I DID look and look and look! Sometimes more q / a are good because they help us find things! OH, and I haven't read that one yet but if it tells how to, as you intimated, actually RUN PHP inside a file marked html, that would be a great thing - DEFINITELY better in some respects. . . . But I am so glad you commented.

@ADyson OH WAIT?! I just read it and he IS using a php file?! I'm not sure what that one's about yet but it's NOT a duplicate!

The facts in the answer: "_You should make sure that following are given:
PHP on your server
Files have to end with ".php"
Use open Tag <?php and not <?_" are still true in all cases, in order to execute PHP. And there are alternative answers, should you prefer it, for configuring Apache to pass .html files through the PHP interpreter.

If you prefer, it  could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109537/php-in-html-not-parsing, or a few others. Doesn't really matter. The point is that the problem description and solution are already widely available and well documented on Stackoverflow, not to mention in multiple other places online.

@ADyson ...I'm not arguing! ...Frankly, I'd seen so many examples of mixed html and php, the filename issue just never came up in my head. And I'm not blaming anyone, just observing my own path - and lamenting the wasted time! BUT DELIGHTED I found this solution. ... I note nobody else cited the "callback" issue. This only really occurred for me when I wanted to get rid of the two-file solution in favor of one file... -shrug- Whatever. THANKS for your help! ;-)

No problem, glad it's helped. Not sure what you're referring to by "callback" in this scenario though? Do you mean the file posting back to itself? If you had a HTML file and a separate PHP script then naturally this problem wouldn't occur if you didn't previously have any <?php blocks in the .html file.

@ADyson When posting, in the two-file scenario, the "action" is performed by the PHP in another script, but when the form and action handling are in the same script, I perceive it as self-referential, often described in other venues as a "callback to one's self", a mild form of recursion - no desire to confuse! What I meant was this issue only came up for me when I tried to do that, but nobody else's questions had anything to do with it. -shrug- Different paths! ...Figuring this out - front-end processing - has released me to a HUGE body of work I've long wanted to do but didn't know how!

The root cause is including a PHP block in a .html file, regardless of what you're actually using it for. If you'd checked the View Source of the page, or using element inspector, or looking carefully at what the page was actually posting back to, you'd hopefully have noticed that the PHP code was coming out as PHP code, and hadn't been turned into a URL in the resulting HTML output of the page (which would the result of the server having executed it before sending the content to the browser), it might have set you thinking that the PHP wasn't running, and helped you search it more easily :-)

P.S. Just as an aside, a lot of application designers are actually moving away from the setup you seem to be moving towards - they are keeping the UI and the server-side code separate, so that the server-side (PHP in your case) code can be used as the backend for multiple different user interfaces (e.g. web app, mobile app, desktop client, automated service etc) rather than being deeply entangled with a specific UI. If you use JS/AJAX to send HTTP requests to the backend asynchronously from your HTML page, you can achieve that separation without worrying about postbacks etc

As an extension to that, it then leads onto using front-end frameworks such as Vue or React to build the web-facing part of it more rapidly, or even cross-platform frameworks which can spit out a web app and a mobile app from one build. Of course you may not need or want any of that, but it's just remarking on the fact that you seemed to have a HTML file and a PHP file separate, rather than one monolithic thing, which lends itself better to a modern API-based architecture and thus greater flexibility. Just something to ponder on.

@ADyson Well.... I'm one of those who has advocated keeping them separate for about three decades now! You misunderstand my current need. . . I've got about a quarter million lines of Java, several tens of Ks of lines of C, etc, that together implement a very robust library that provides a full API AND "Application Server" that keeps the application code and database separate for a LOT of good reasons, especially security. The need ATM is a bit of "glue layer" for when actual application deployment isn't appropriate. I'm SURE it can be done better, but "Earth Science is broke." ...

Where does PHP come into that, then?

@ADyson And I don't mean broken: budgets for software systems ... This is the wrong venue to discuss, but in short: inter- and intra- organizational rivalries, Military Industrial Complex vendors, congress' budgeting process and, and, and... However, this system has supported what was at one time the world's largest publicly known database...

@ADyson ... Like I said, "A Glue Layer" that can bring a lot of capability to bear via some simple interfaces - in short, it's some authenticating of who's who, some meta-data collection and then some secure file transfers where the more profound connections are happening on the server-side from the data so gathered...
